# business activity description announcement rejection and speed of legal validity of the change

Tags: european-union, business

In a hypothetical scenario, Mr. Peter owns a company. He intends to change the business activity description, e.g. instead of chocolate he intends to sell tennis shoes.

Two questions please:

1. Can such a change be rejected by the business register?
2. Can he start to manufacture and sell tennis shoes the very same day he announced the change?

jurisdiction: EU

Thank you.

Comment: I would think that the answer isn't fully general. If one is shifting into or out of a highly regulated industry (e.g. nuclear power, pharmaceuticals, banking) it would be presumably harder than changing the kinds of goods sold in retail stores. Also, presumably whether you can change "on the day of the announcement" has a lot to do with how much preparation you do and how judiciously you time your announcement. As a matter of sheer logistics, a major chance of business is impossible to achieve the day you decide to do it.

Comment: But if there is no factory producing chocolate yet, and the company exists for 1 day, can such a change be done quickly, i.e. in one day? (there is no big regulation of these simple products, like in banking..)

Comment: I don't think there are EU-wide rules on this, but that this would depend on the member state laws of the countries where this company does business.

Answer (score 1):

### The purpose of a company is not recorded on the register and, yes, it can be done immediately

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

Unless the company is a [special purpose company](https://asic.gov.au/for-business/registering-a-company/steps-to-register-a-company/special-purpose-companies/), it can do any legal thing it’s directors want it to do and it can do one thing on Monday and a different thing on Tuesday.

For example, the oil company Shell started out as an import-export business importing predominantly seashells.

Comment: By purpose of a company, do you mean business activity description? (i.e. what does it do to make a profit)